# Website with 2 separate WordPress blogs

Tags: wordpress, blogs

I have a website, which runs an integrated wordpress blog, the wordpress was installed by my hosting company and it was a one click install. I then went into my FTP and took all the files from the original style and edited it to look like my website and still function. this is all well and good.

However, I would like to run another page on a separate wordpress blog (so there is basically two seperate archiving systems in place as one of the pages is a blog, and the other is articles which are produced monthly).

is there anyway to do this with the one click install, for example through the WP admin Control panel?

Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Wordpress MU (Multisite) to accomplish this or just install another Wordpress instance.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Create_A_Network

Are the two instances you want running on the same domain? Different domains?

In regards to the one click install from your web host, I'm not sure which web host it is or if there are any options for this on there.

Please clarify if you have any further issues. :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use two blogs by the two methods

> 1. Install wordpress on SubDomain like  **site.domain.com**
> 2. Install wordpress on SubDirectories like  **domain.com/site**

And then you can use both of your site in one another according to your needs and requirements ...